# Can we write $Bv_i$ in the form $\beta_1v_1+\beta_2v_2+\beta_3v_3+...\beta_nv_n$ where $\beta_1,\beta_2,..,\beta_n\in\Bbb R$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let us consider a linear transformation $L:V\to V$

The matrix $A$ corresponds to $L$ in a certain basis $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,...,v_n\}$ of $V$.

If $AB=BA$, can we write $Bv_i$ in the form $\beta_1v_1+\beta_2v_2+\beta_3v_3+...\beta_nv_n$ where $\beta_1,\beta_2,..,\beta_n\in\Bbb R$ ? Why? [Where, $1\leq i\leq n$]

P.S: $A$ and $B$ are invertible $n\times n$ matrices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $B$ is a matrix then $Bv_i$ does not make sense in general. Assuming you actually meant that $B : V \to V$ and $BL = LB$ (although this assumption is unnecessary).

Since $Bv_i \in V$, and $\{v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n\}$ is a basis for $V$, then $Bv_i = \beta_1 v_1 + \cdots + \beta_n v_n$ for some $\beta_1, \ldots, \beta_n \in \mathbb{R}$ by the definition of basis.

Comment: How do you know $Bv_i\in V$ ?

Comment: @Blue What exactly do you mean by $Bv_i$? How can you multiply a matrix with a vector from a general vector space $V$?

Comment: Well, $B$ is a $n\times n$ matrix. Also, any vector like $v_i$ in $V$ can be written as linear combination of $n$ independent vectors like $v_1,v_2,...$ (i.e. the basis). So surely $v_i$ can be represented as an $n \times 1$ column matrix (in $\Bbb R^{n}$ by isomorphism). So, I think it can concluded from there that $Bv_i\in V$ ?

Comment: @Blue Yes, you can do that, that effectively makes $B$ an operator from $V$ to $V$. Formally,  the matrix $B$ induces a map $\tilde{B} : V \to V$, defined on the basis $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ as $\tilde{B}v_j = \sum_{i=1}^n (Bv_j)_iv_i$ where $Bv_j$ is the matrix $B$ multiplied by the representation of the vector $v_j$ in the basis $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$, just like you said, and $(Bv_j)_i$ is its $i$-th element. Now $\tilde{B}v_j \in V$.